# User logged in status in "sign in with google" api library

Tags: google-signin, sign-in-with-google

I am unable to figure out that how can I check when an user visit my website that he/she have already logged in with google on my website. It was previously possible but that method has been depreciated by google

Comment: its client side javascript they will need to login again

Comment: but it was possible with previous library

Comment: The current library doesnt work that way.